Bibliography citation with a single link when the citation contains multiple entries sorted as a range
I need to set the bibliography citation with a single link when the citation contains multiple entries sorted as a range (using an en-dash), and the link point to set using first cite for that cases. My MWE is below
Compiler: LuaLaTeX-dev.exe (2024)
My current output: (Default having a separate link for each cite)

Expected Output: 10-12 have a single link (The single link using the reference number 10 only)

\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}

The atomic structure of \cite{Grant1969,Ignatiev1972} the reconstructed Ir(001) \cite{Ignatiev1972,Heilmann1979} surface was clarified more than half a century
ago. It consists of a quasi-hexagonal top layer residing on a semi-infinite stack of quadratic layers
in a similar way to the reconstructed Au(001) and Pt(001)\cite{Grant1969,Ignatiev1972,Heilmann1979}.
Alongside the clean surface.

\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{Grant1969}
J.T. Grant, A LEED study of the Ir(100) surface, Surf. Sci. 18 (1969) 228. doi:10.1016/0039-6028(69)90167-8.


\bibitem{Ignatiev1972}
A. Ignatiev, A.V. Jones, T.N. Rhodin, LEED investigations of xenon single crystal films and their use in studying the Ir(100) surface, Surf. Sci. 30 (1972) 573. doi:10.1016/0039-6028(72)90047-7.


\bibitem{Heilmann1979}
P. Heilmann, K. Heinz, K. Muller, The superstructures of the clean Pt(100) and Ir(100), Surf. Sci. 83 (1979) 487. doi:10.1016/0039-6028(79)90058-X.

\bibitem{Hammer2014}
R. Hammer, A. Sander, S. Forster, M. Kiel, K. Meinel, W. Widdra, Surface reconstruction of Au(001): high-resolution real-space and reciprocal-space inspection, Phys. Rev. B 90 (2014) 035446. doi:10.1103/PhysRevB.90.035446.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Off-topic: Since you use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, I can see no reason for using \"{o} and \"{u} to input the letters ö and ü.

Just out of idle curiosity: What's the use case for making a citation call-out less useful to your readers? (I would have guessed that making the doi strings into hyperlinks would be higher up on the list of typesetting priorities.)

@Mico, I am using the dummy content.
